# Can't assign new keymap: Unsupported key: Unknown

Tags: customization

I can't change keymaps, I just get "Unsupported key: unknown". I am on a Mac with a Danish keyboard layout. Is anyone else experiencing this?

[image: Unsupported key: unknown]

- Blender 2.82a
- OS: MacOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: It's not exactly a bug, more like a missing feature in Blender. Whether it's MacOS keyboards or international keyboards, Blender's support for them has always been... [not exactly great](https://developer.blender.org/T72692)

Comment: You might open a new issue on [Blender's Bug Tracker](https://developer.blender.org/), or add your issue to the one I linked above. Who knows, maybe they start working on it...